# yii pdf download by tcpdf

Tags: php, yii, tcpdf

In my site, I want to export a view to pdf so I used pdf extension:

```
            $mPDF1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf();

            $mPDF1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf('', 'A5');

            $mPDF1->WriteHTML($this->render('TLR_22', array(), true));

            $stylesheet = file_get_contents(Yii::app()->themeManager->baseUrl.'/default/css/sheets/style');
            $mPDF1->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);

            $mPDF1->Output();
```

It exported html to pdf but not load css althought I changed path to absolute path like this:

```
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('D:/xampp/htdocs/Yii/DialSetup/themes/default/css/sheets/style.css');
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks... :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=254), it looks like you need to set the style, and then write the output, e.g.:

```
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('style.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
```

Also, have you verified that $stylesheet contains the information you expect it to?